# How to check title of the post with its tag in the same time

Tags: php, wordpress, function, post, plugins

I'm using wordpress. Im working on  Don't submit post if post title exists with the same **TAG** how can i achieve that ?

The code Below is only checking the post title and its already working if it has the same post title it will echo **This post is already posted would u like to post a another one** How can i achieve checking the post title with the post tag ? if the post title is existed and its using the post tag it will echo this again **This post is already posted would u like to post a another one**

```
<?php

    //jQuery to send AJAX request 
    function duplicate_titles_enqueue_scripts( $hook ) {

        if( !in_array( $hook, array( 'post.php', 'post-new.php' , 'edit.php'))) return;
        wp_enqueue_script('duptitles',
        wp_enqueue_script('duptitles',plugins_url().'/duplicate-title-validate/js/duptitles.js',
                                                           array( 'jquery' )), array( 'jquery' )  );
    }

    add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'duplicate_titles_enqueue_scripts', 2000 );
    add_action('wp_ajax_title_checks', 'duplicate_title_checks_callback');


    /// callback ajax 
    function duplicate_title_checks_callback() {

            function title_checks() {

                global $wpdb;

                $title = $_POST['post_title'];
                $post_id = $_POST['post_id'];

                $titles = "SELECT post_title FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_status = 'publish' AND post_type = 'post' 
                            AND post_title = '{$title}' AND ID != {$post_id} ";

                $results = $wpdb->get_results($titles);

                if($results) {
                    return "<span style='color:red'>". _e( 'Duplicate title detected, please change the title.' , 'dublicate-title-validate' ) ." </span>";
                } else {
                    return '<span style="color:green">'._e('This title is unique.' , 'dublicate-title-validate').'</span>';
                }

            }       
            echo title_checks();
            die();
        }

    // this chek backend title and if Duplicate update status draft .
    function duplicate_titles_wallfa_bc( $post )
    {
        global $wpdb ;
        $title = $_POST['post_title'] ;
        $post_id = $post ;



        $wtitles = "SELECT post_title FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_status = 'publish' AND post_type = 'post' 
                            AND post_title = '{$title}' AND ID != {$post_id} " ;

        $wresults = $wpdb->get_results( $wtitles ) ;

        if ( $wresults )
        {
            $wpdb->update( $wpdb->posts, array( 'post_status' =>
                    'draft' ), array( 'ID' => $post ) ) ;
            $arr_params = array( 'message' => '10', 'wallfaerror' => '1' )  ;      
            $location = add_query_arg( $arr_params , get_edit_post_link( $post , 'url' ) ) ;
            wp_redirect( $location  ) ;

            exit ; 


        }
    }


    add_action( 'publish_post',
        'duplicate_titles_wallfa_bc' ) ;

    /// handel error for back end 
    function not_published_error_notice() {
        if(isset($_GET['wallfaerror']) == 1 ){
                   ?>
                   <div class="updated">
                   <p style='color:red' ><?php _e(' This post is already posted would u like to post a another one. ' , 'dublicate-title-validate') ?></p>
                   </div>
                   <?php
            }
    }
    add_action( 'admin_notices', 'not_published_error_notice' );        


    function duplicate_titles_wallfa_action_init()
    {
    // Localization
    load_plugin_textdomain('dublicate-title-validate',false,dirname(plugin_basename(__FILE__)).'/langs/');
    }

    // Add actions
    add_action('init', 'duplicate_titles_wallfa_action_init');




    function disable_autosave()
    {
        wp_deregister_script( 'autosave' ) ;
    }
    add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'disable_autosave' ) ;

    ?>
```

**AJAX**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    function checkTitleAjax(title, id,post_type) {
        var data = {
            action: 'title_checks',
            post_title: title,
            post_type: post_type,
            post_id: id
        };
        $.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
            $('#message').remove();
            $('#poststuff').prepend('<div id=\"message\" class=\"updated below-h2 fade \"><p>'+response+'</p></div>');
        }); 
    };
    $('#title').change(function() {
        var title = $('#title').val();
        var id = $('#post_ID').val();
        var post_type = $('#post_type').val();
        checkTitleAjax(title, id,post_type);
    });

});
```

This is the Explanation 
Example

**Post Name - Post Tag - Result**

**post 1 - post1 - allowed**

**post 2 - post1 - allowed**

post 1 - post1 - This post is already posted would u like to post a another one. (because it has the same value of the first post )

Comment: Is your question how to disable the submit if the title is the same?

Comment: @PatrickMlr How to disable the submit if the title and tag is the same with the existed one, the existing code is only disabling you to submit the post if u have the same title and it will echo This post is already posted would u like to post a another one. i want to achieve if the post has the same title and tag it will not submit